# Can I use a 27.5 fork on a original 29er (2015 Cannondale Tramount 3)?

Tags: fork, cannondale

I have a Cannondale Tramount 3 e-bike that I would like to make better and lighter in every way I can for as little cost as possible, but with quality used or discounted parts.

Can someone help me with a tip for which fork to use (now it has a Suntour XCR, which is over 2.6kg) I think that with a 27.5 it will stand a litle more on its head but I think I still will have place for a 2.3 x 29 inch wheel. Originally it had 1.9, now it has lightweight 2.2 Maxxis tyres.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @KorErCannondalen. Nice to see you here, and good to see you've taken the [tour]. I recommend [ask] to help you improve your question. Don't worry about your language skills; we can help. [Edit](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/posts/42327/edit) your question to remove most of the discussion and chat that is not essential to the basic technical question you're asking, and try to focus on *how* you can solve the problem. Particular product recommendations are off topic here because they get out of date quickly.

Comment: So thank for your understanding of difference in language skills..

Comment: But how would you edit this question of mine?

Comment: And can you help the dialogue to start and give a answer to my question ..or should I ask it again ...after editing it and maybe direct the question on to : switching from Suntour to RS SID XX light weight and usefull..?

Comment: Or is it so that people dont think one can place a 27.5 on a 29`r ..one can but I want to discuss the pros and cons on the subject and also the difference in  maybe a Lauf spring fork wich have a suspension I havent tried yet, but can be a challenger (900grams)

Comment: Or should I just throw a cheap Suntour Epixon (120USD and about 1600grams with remote adjust) 100-120mm ..?

Comment: You should be fine using a 27.5 on a 29er frame, that is what the new "plus size" fad is all about. Using a big fat tire ends up being about the same size as a normal 29er. Should be a fun build!

Comment: I've suggested an edit which I think makes your question clearer and only includes the relevant information. If I've distorted it or removed anything that's important, please feel free to revert and change it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The key to swapping forks is the axle to crown measurement - the distance from the center of the front axle to the seat of the crown race that is the lowest part of the headset. You want the replacement to be as close to the original as possible, to preserve the designed geometry. There are forks that can take either a 27.5 or a 29er wheel.
The suspension fork *is* heavy, if your goal is light weight then you should consider the correct length carbon rigid fork. You will need to balance weight, cost...and what is available. Remember that you need to find a fork with the same steerer diameter - you can't put a tapered fork on a bike built to accept a standard 1 1/8" steerer.
The difference between a 27.5 and a 29 can be large or small, depending on the tire size you choose - if you put a 27.5 wheel on the front with a 27.5 plus tire (3 inches wide) then the out diameter is nearly the same as a regular 29er tire, with a rigid fork you would have some suspension, too, without the weight.
Good luck!